# Forgot password for android device not able to reset it

Tags: factory-reset, password, locked-out, android-11, vivo

I recently bought a new phone and forgot about the old one, and now I can't remember the password for the old device. I tried

1. google findmyphone: didn't work
2. hard reset: asking for the password
3. ADB : USB debugging is on but can't accept the pop up

Is there any way I can reset the password of the device?

Comment: The password it is asking for after hard reset is the Factory Reset Protection (FRP). It just wants to know your Google password (not the device pin/password). So if you can use Google FindMyPhone you should know the used Google password and be able to unlock the device after factory/hard reset.

Comment: @Robert the password asked is 'indeed' the prev lockscreen password, not the Google account password. OEMs these days store lockscreen password on some separate partition => resetting /data and /system doesnt make the phone 'forget' the prev password. Refer my answer for the possible solution

Answer (score 0):

OEMs these days store lockscreen password on some separate partition => resetting /data and /system doesnt make the phone 'forget' the prev password.

But there is a solution that works on most of the devices (the solution is flashing all partitions without formatting the partitions that store imei). Get the firmware flash tool for your device (eg sp flash for mediatek devices, something similar exists for qualcomm devices too).. A googling in the format "how to flash stock firmware on <your device>" would lead you to the right page.

I can't give any specific guide since you haven't mentioned your device model and there exists no generic guide except the outline I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried using the qfil flash tool, But could not figure it out how to actually flash it. 
I'm using Vivo z1 pro with android 11